# OAuth 2.0 public client impersonation

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I'd like to develop a native application (for a mobile phone) that uses [OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23) to access protected resources from a resource API. As defined in [section 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-2.1) the *type* of my client is `public`.

Upon registration, the Authorization Server provides a `client_id` for public identification and a `redirect_uri`.

The client will make use of [Authorization Code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-1.3.1) to receive it's Authorization Grant from the Authorization Server. This all seems secure (if implemented correctly) against any attacker in the middle.

In [section 10.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-10.2) client impersonation is discussed. In my case, the resource owner grants the client authorization by providing it's credentials via the user agent to the Authorization Server. This section discusses that the Authorization Server:

> SHOULD utilize other means to protect resource owners from such
> potentially malicious clients. For example, the authorization server
> can engage the resource owner to assist in identifying the client and
> its origin.

My **main concern** is that it's easy to impersonate my client once the `client_id` and `redirect_uri` is retrieved.
Due to the nature of a public client, this can either be easily reverse engineered. Or in my case, the project will be open source, so this information can be retrieved from the web.

As far as I've understood from *section 10.2*, it's the resource owner's responsibility to check that the client is legitimate by comparing with what the Authorization Server SHOULD assist with.

In my experience with third party applications requesting an Authorization Grant from me, all I get is a page with some information about the client that actually should be requesting that grant. Based on pure logical sense, I can only judge if the client that's requesting the grant is actually the client that the Authorization Server is telling me who it should be.

So whenever we are dealing with [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) (which I think occurs frequently), isn't it true that impersonators can easily access protected resources if the resource owner just grants them (which might identically look like my legitimate client) authorization?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR - You want oauth access tokens to be issued only to valid clients - in this case devices that installed your app, yes?

First - Oauth2 has multiple workflows for issuing tokens. When YOU are running the Oauth2 service and its issuing tokens to devices running YOUR app, authorization code / redirect URL is not the relevant workflow. I suggest you read my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17670574/116524 .

Second - No luck here. Just run your services entirely on HTTPS. There is no real way to know whether the client registration request is coming from an app installed from the official app store. You can store bake some secret into the app, but it can be found via reverse engineering. The only possible way this could possibly happen can be some sort of authentication information being provided by the app store itself, which does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

"The only possible way this could possibly happen can be some sort of authentication information being provided by the app store itself, which does not exist yet."

Doesn't apple app store provide such info?